Lamb wave derivation: Elastic wave propagation in a thin sheet
I am trying to follow the derivation for the phase velocity for elastic waves with large wavelengths compared to sheet thickness, propagating in a floating ice sheet, as described in Propagation of elastic waves in a floating ice sheet by Press and Ewing . This seems to give us the standard equation for lamb wave propagation in geophysics.
I am trying to follow the chain of logic between equation 8, the period equation, and equations 14 and 15, which are apparently what the period equation can be reduced to when assuming the wavelength is large compared to the thickness of the sheet. That is, going from:
$$2PQ + D\delta \mbox{Sinh}(\xi H) \mbox{Sinh}(\eta H) + P\delta \mbox{Cosh}(\xi H)\mbox{Cosh}(\eta H) = 0 $$
To:
$$ P + Q\delta \mbox{Sinh}(\xi H)\mbox{Sinh}(\eta H)/2Q + \delta = 0 $$
$$ Q + \delta/2 = 0 $$
I have assumed that given the angle is small, $\mbox{Cosh}(\xi H) = \mbox{Cosh}(\eta H) = 1$. Using this assumption and some basic rearranging I got to:
$$ P + Q\delta \mbox{Sinh}(\xi H) \mbox{Sinh}(\eta H) /2Q + P\delta /2Q = 0 $$
However I'm really not sure where to progress from here, nor really how they managed to get the two equations from the one initial period equation.
If anyone has any pointers on how to proceed, or any resources that might be helpful for this derivation, I'd greatly appreciate it!

I am pretty sure that there is an error with one of the equations. Start from
$$2PQ + P\delta + Q\delta \sinh\left(\xi H\right) \sinh(\eta H)=0, $$
where I've already assumed small angles. Now, If you divide by $P$ instead of by $Q$, you arrive at
$$2Q + \delta + \frac{Q}{P}\delta\sinh\left(\xi H\right) \sinh(\eta H)=0.  $$
The paper states that "the factor $\sinh\left(\xi H\right) \sinh(\eta H)$ is neglected in $(15)$ and carried in $(14)$". The large wavelength condition is simply $\gg kH$, but, from the definitions of $\xi$ and $\eta$ you can deduce it also implies $\gg \xi H$ and $\gg \eta H$. So you can neglect the $\sinh$ term as $0$ and then
$$2Q+\delta =0\to Q+\delta/2=0 .$$
That's equation $(15)$. I think the mistake is in equation $(14)$.
EDIT: To be clear, you can also get the result from your equation, as follows
$$P+P\delta/2Q =0 \to 1+ \frac{\delta }{2Q}=0 \to Q + \delta/2 = 0. $$
You can't get it from equation $(14)$ in the paper because they forgot the terms that accompany $\delta$.

Thank you for your help! Sorry for taking a second to get back to this. I like your approach for equation 15, do you have any theories on where the mistake came in for equation 14? I don't really feel confident enough in my working to determine a "proper form" for the equation to take.

I think they simply forgot to write the $\delta$ term as $P\delta/2Q$ in equation 14. However, they probably had equation 15 correctly derived somewhere else and so that equation is correct.
